# Derived class using variables from abstract base class C++

Tags: c++, derived-class

I created an abstract `Light` class with fields and methods common for all the lights and now I try to derive a `Directional Light` from it.

```
class Light
{
public:
    unsigned int strength;
    Color color;
    unsigned int index;

    Light() {};
    virtual ~Light() = 0;

    virtual pointLuminosity() = 0;
};

class DirectionalLight : public Light
{
public:
    Vector direction;
    DirectionalLight(const unsigned int &_strength, [...] ): strength(_strength), [...] {}
};
```

The above code results in an error:

```
error: class 'DirectionalLight' does not have any field named 'strength'
```

What is the proper way to derive all the fields from `Light` class and use them in the `DirectionalLight` objects?

Comment: many problems occur. 1. word: use "field" not "variable" .2 very rarely public fields are OK 3. Fields are not derrivevd in OOP theory. 4 but derrive class constins fields from poarent, there are useable when >=protected

Comment: and next. 5 very bad is initialisation of parent fields (introduce contructor in Light)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use strength anywhere but an initialiser list. This works

```
DirectionalLight(const unsigned int &_strength) { strength = _strength; }
```

Alternatively you can add a constructor to `Light`

```
class Light
{
public:
    unsigned int strength;
    Light(unsigned s) : strength(s) {}
};

DirectionalLight(const unsigned int &_strength) : Light(_strength) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in initializer list since `strength` is not member of `DirectionalLight`. You have to initialize derived member in the body of constructor or call base class constructor in the initializer list of the derived class constructor.

For example:

```
DirectionalLight(const unsigned int &_strength): { strength = _strength; }
```

Or:

```
Light(int _strength) : strength(_strength) {}
...
DirectionalLight(const unsigned int &_strength): Light(_strength) { }
```

Second option is prefered, also `strength` in `Light` should be protected, so the encapsulation is not destroyed.